# Dimensions of the Curiosity Rover?

Tags: mars, curiosity, dimensions

Does anyone know where I can find more detailed dimensions of the Mars Curiosity rover?  For example, what are various dimensions of the boogie rocker system?  Or the dimensions of the main body itself, or the dimensions of the arm?

Comment: Are you posting this question before or after trying to search the Internet first? Surely those specifications are available somewhere!

Answer (score 11):

This PDF has [a side view with some dimensions](http://trs-new.jpl.nasa.gov/dspace/bitstream/2014/41421/1/08-0699.pdf).

[image: MSL side view]

The [Press kit](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/press_kits/MSLLanding.pdf) has lots of information.

And NASA has made a [3D model](http://nasa3d.arc.nasa.gov/detail/mars-rover-curiosity) which you can open and measure.

Comment: Ha - i didn't know about those 3D models. That's going to be handy!

Comment: That is really awesome, thank you.  For anyone else that cares:

From measuring the 3D model, I think the body is 1.4m x 1.9m x 0.5m

The boogie bar is 100mm thick.

Comment: Thank you for posting this image. I needed to check if body dimensions in my model are correct. Main "box" is 1846x460x1150. The width can be counted as 1120-660 so it is OK. I am using model for Sketchup.

Comment: The link to the diagram has since died. For future searches, it can currently be found here, https://trs.jpl.nasa.gov/handle/2014/41421 , which is also archived on archive.org.

Answer (score 1):

I've also been interested in having more precise dimensions. A comment on the answer says "surely those specifications are available somewhere" but I've found that not to be the case, and there is much ambiguity in whatever measurements are out there.

For example, it's commonly referenced that Curiosity's wheels are 50 cm diameter, but does this include the treads/cleats/grousers, or is that measurement just to the outer skin of the wheel? And how wide are the wheels? A couple years ago I never found a figure for the width, and estimated it to be 45 cm from photos. This year, I see figures of 40 cm. But today when I take the detailed 3D printable model and scale it so the diameter is correct (for reference, I'm using 139%), the wheel width is 45 cm. So, which is it?

In another comment, I see measurements for the main part of the body estimated from the 3D printable model. But I just measured it myself, and I get different figures: about 1560 long by 1100 wide by 380 high, if that helps anybody. Part of the problem is the multiple levels of ambiguity. Do we agree on what the "box" part is? I mean the rectangular prism part that doesn't include the angled back where the reactor is. But even if we agree on that, the sides of that box are not planar (this is evident in detailed photos, or the 3D printable model), so are we measuring to the innermost outer panels or the outermost outer panels or to the edge things that go around them...?

From photos and the 3D printable model, the thickness (diameter) of the front leg appears to be just shy of 9 cm.

Looking at the side view PDF diagram, it seems the angles of the legs are about 12.5 and 20 deg on the upper suspension, and about 30 and -5 deg on the lower suspension. However, looking at the 3D printable model, the upper suspension appears to have angles of about 10 and 16 deg, and the lower of about 37 and -2 deg. This means the model matches the diagram for the lower suspension (total angle of 35 deg) but not for the upper suspension (32.5 vs. 26 deg). This is not a measurement error; if I hold up a printout of the diagram over an orthgraphic side view of the 3D printable model on a monitor, I can see the angles don't match. They disagree by about 6.5 degrees. So, which is correct: the diagram, the model, or neither?

The 3m length appears to be from the front tangent of the front wheels to the back tip of the reactor part of the body; that is, this is the total extent of the rover in its direction of travel. Width is given as 2.8m, which obvious includes the wheels. I believe the middle wheels are the furthest out, but by how much compared to the front and rear wheels? Are the front and rear wheels aligned with each other? So many simple questions seem to lack definitive answers.